# OCI with long double

Tags: c++, oracle

I'm developing a C++ library with oracle OCI library. I'm loading from a Oracle Database 11g database. Here I need to load large values with decimal places. In this case I need to use long double instead of double. I'm not sure whether OCI supports for long double.
According to the documentation SQLT_FLT is for float and double only. Can someone let me know whether OCI supports for long double and if so how to retrieve them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

According to the [server docs on floats](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22294), the 'native' C types support up to double precision (`BINARY_DOUBLE`). However, the [NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289) type can store:

> - Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10-130 to 9.99...9 x 10125 with **up to 38 significant digits**
> - Negative numbers from -1 x 10-130 to 9.99...99 x 10125 with **up to 38 significant digits**

which is more precision than `long double` on x86/amd64.

So, you'd need to use that type instead of `BINARY_*`. Sadly, the [developer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci03typ.htm#autoId11) say:

> You should not need to use `NUMBER` as an external datatype. If you do use it, Oracle returns numeric values in its internal 21-byte binary format and will expect this format on input. The following discussion is included for completeness only.

On the other hand, there are also docs on:

- [using the OCINumber](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci12oty.htm#i434059) type;
- [OCI NUMBER Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci19map003.htm#CEGCAEFC).

AFAICS [OCINumberFromReal()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci19map003.htm#i455143) supports `long double`; and if you want even more precision, then you could use [OCINumberFromText()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci19map003.htm#i460199) with decimal string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea. :) As I'm new to this area,Appreciate if you can provide a link or some help on a sample code which provide a solution for my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't ever work with Oracle. But the first link in the bulleted list provides some lengthy example you could start with.